# Arduino number detection

Tags: sensors

I am planning for a project but i am stuck with a task and hope you could help me. My work is to note down a number which is actually a set of readings displayed on a meter and store it on a arduino. My problem is that i need a detection technique so that i could record the number or extract the number from a image or video if u suggest to use a camera or recorder or purely can be a sensor. Thank you guys, waiting for you.

Comment: What kind of meter? Analog, digital, leds, lcd, ...?

Comment: What exactly is it you are trying to do? What does this "meter" measure? What form does that measurement and display take?

Comment: Abstraction is (often) a good thing. But for this question, we're going to need the details of this specific meter. How does the display work, can we wire into the display? How does the end sensor work, can we just replace it? Best would be if you upload an image and description of the sensor.

Answer (score 3):

"Number detection" sounds like you're trying to interpret a 7-segment digital display - is that correct? One way would be to place 7 photo-detectors (times the number of digits), one per segment, on or at the face of the display. Sample the photo-detectors and create a 7-bit code representing the lit segments, into a byte. You could start with a simple lookup table that translates from code to the digit it represents. You might need to get clever about interpreting codes that shouldn't appear, but do, due, perhaps to light leakage, ambient lighting, or noise. The "lit" segments may only be lit for a fraction of second at a time, and only one at a time, if the display is multiplexed, so your sampling algorithm will have to take that into account. Must the display remain visible? You might need optics or optical fibers to view the segments without obstructing them.

Comment: `+1 for the extreme "hacky" end-product that can be placed ontop of an 7segment and read it's value.` But how is this superior to just reading the pins/lines that go to the 7segment? (If we have access to them, I would suggest reading those out).

Comment: Thanks! And of course, it isn't better. I tried to guess what the real requirement was based on the OP's question - is this a design-course exercise? - and to answer that. If I could have connectivity to the system, I'd do as you suggest. If I could have access to its firmware, I'd transmit the values by, e.g. serial.  In any case, we can't answer for real without a better spec.